# How can I make "and" be a working alias for && in Bash?

Tags: bash, alias

I want to be able to use `and` instead of `&&` in Bash.

I tried `alias and=&&` but the behavior is not the same.

```
steven% echo 'hi' && echo 'bi'  (git)-[yako.botrank-rate-limit-status]-
hi
bi
steven% echo 'hi' and echo 'bi'
hi and echo bi
```

Comment: Alias works at the beginning of a command only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this is my first answer on this stackexchange so please bear with me)

The other answer seems to be correct that this is not possible, however as a workaround I have considered the following code because I also wanted to do something like this:

```
alias and='read and1 && read and2 && eval $and1 && eval $and2'
```

this post has warnings about using the "eval" command, and some suggestions of what you could use instead that would work as well or better: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable

this will allow you to do two commands, one after the other, in a kind of polish notation. So, you would type "and"+enter, type in a command then enter, then the next command and enter, and it would then run each command. (and command command)

you could also chain these together by typing and+enter, then typing the first command then enter, then typing and+enter again (making "and" the second command to execute). (and command (and command command))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in bash.

Bash provides no syntax to override an operator.  In other words, all operators and reserved words are hard-coded.  Search for yourself in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Also note, the [Bash Reference Manual: Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases) states, "Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the **first word** of a simple command."

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey) to create abbreviations.

So for example, typing `and[TAB]` will expand to `&&`.